# scroll draggable div when it reach the bottom of the browser

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Can anyone help me get this jquery code to automatically scroll the page up or down when you pull the div up or down?

Code #1:

```
$(".DragBox").draggable({
start: function ()
{
$(this).parent().droppable("enable");
},
revert: true
});
```

Code #2:

```
$(".DragDestination101").droppable(
{
drop: function (event, ui)
{
var elem = $(ui.draggable[0]);
elem.css("left", "");
elem.css("top", "");
elem.appendTo(this);
elem.children("input").val("101");
$(this).droppable("disable");
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below URL jsFiddle :

[**Your answer**](http://jsfiddle.net/cr79V/6/)

Could you please try below function....

```
$(function () {
            $(".DragBox").draggable();
            $(".DragDestination101").droppable({
                drop: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this)
          .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
          .find("p")
            .html("Dropped!");
                }
            });
        });
```

Below URL explain same which you need to fix....

[Try this URL >> Droppable](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/)

Comment: @fletcher Could you please update me, This answer is work for you or not?

Comment: It's does not Work... :(

Comment: @fletcher please see your answer from jsfiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/cr79V/6/